# Export(or map) List data to external MSSQL table

Tags: bcs, sql-server, export, sql, custom-bcs

There are many references about External Lists, where you make a Sharepoint list from SQL database table.

In my case, I need to do the opposite - I have SharePoint list, and I want to map it to an external SQL table, to allow another team to access it in SQL Server in read-only mode.

Is there a way to do this? Of course, I will not give them access to Sharepoint DB directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Powershell script to export External list to Sql on nightly basis(Task Scheduler)

Please look into following URL which will be helpful to you for getting power shell scripts
http://www.terrymarshall.com.au/Blog/tabid/162/EntryId/165/SharePoint-2010-Exporting-Lists-To-SQL-Server-Part-2.aspx

http://community.obilogic.co.uk/blogs/teamblog/archive/2012/04/22/sharepoint-2010-export-splist-data-into-sql-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Hi Amit! Thank You for response, I put +1 for this method, dut I think there should be way to Map list to SQL table in 'online mode', maybe using server features like BCS(we have Sharepoint 2010 Server)

Comment: Hi Gennady.This might help if you wan to use bcs::http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-programmatically-work-with-external-lists-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I resolved with sharepoint SSIS SQL connectors, but I'll mark Your proposal as answer becouse You wanted to help and these methods could be possibly working too(cause imho Zimmergren is clever guy :) )